# How to solve Firefox border bug without invalid CSS3 code

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, firefox, w3c

Firefox on Ubuntu adds a dotted border on active elements like input submit if you set a custom border. For example:

```
<input style="border:1px solid black" type="submit"/>
```

I opened a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1598851), but is there a temporary solution until they fix it without using following invalid css3 code?

```
input::-moz-focus-inner {
   border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about this:

[image: Dotted outline on a non-native button]

then it's expected behavior, that's [been in Gecko since the beginning](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/forms.css#776), and I'm not sure why you think it's a bug.

I'm pretty sure you can't disable it without overriding the default stylesheet like you did.